# problems of loading html using wget

Tags: html, bash, wget

I would like to download a html from twitter. I use wget but I can only download a small part of the members because it needs more time for loading the list. How can I download all this html?

I use now, stores the information in usa.dat

```
wget -c -N -p -O usa.dat https://twitter.com/IABM1995/lists/usa/members
```

Comment: Assuming I understand your requirement: I think that is being dynamically generated when the user scrolls down and this I think is through js and wget does not support js at this time. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5852220/how-to-download-dynamic-generated-content-from-webpage

Comment: I will check this link Khanna111, best

Answer (score 0):

check this

[scrape websites with infinite scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519074/scrape-websites-with-infinite-scrolling)